# jQuery, Get object back to original place

Tags: jquery

I could really use some help with a script I'm writing.

Look at this, I have come so far:

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 500, function() { 

        var text = $('div.panel');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.animate({width: 'toggle'});
            $(this).children('span').html('-');     
        } else {
            text.animate({width: 'toggle'});
            $(this).children('span').html('+');     
        }

    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sveningmar/L60dL69b/)

The question is:

1. How do i do so the .box div animate to the left at the same time as
   the panel toggles up?
2. How do i get the .box back on the right place using *'left':
   originLeft* when I'm closing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your own code:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

  if (!$(this).data("originalLeft")) {
    //you store in data() the original left
    $(this).data("originalLeft", $(this).css("left"));
  }

  $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
  var text = $(this).next('div.panel');
  if (text.is(':hidden')) {
    text.animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $(this).children('span').html('-');
  } else {
    text.animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $(this).children('span').html('+');
    //you restore the original left value
    $(this).animate({
      "left": $(this).data("originalLeft") 
    }, 500);
  }

});
```

keep in mind that if you want symultaneous animations you should avoid calling them in the callback function

```
$(".some-selector").animate({left: 10}, 500, function() {/*second animation*/}}
```

will always set up the second animation as the first will end.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaputzu/L60dL69b/15/)

Comment: actually toggles all the text panels

Comment: @charlietfl: not in my configuration... just edited the original fiddle... can you check it? https://jsfiddle.net/lucaputzu/L60dL69b/13/

Comment: Can see what happens when you set specific text in each panel https://jsfiddle.net/L60dL69b/14/

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @charlietfl yup... noticed

Comment: fixed... should be ok now

Answer (score 0):

Store original position on element using `data()` and then you can retrieve that when needed.

As for the simultaneous animations you have the panel being animated in callback of the box animation. Call them at same time.

Also their are various ways to target the associated text panel. Currently you are animating all of them. Following uses `next()`

Am using a class `active` to determine current state of the box

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  var $box = $(this), // store reference to `$(this)` when you use it more than once
    isActive = $box.hasClass('active'),
    $text = $box.next(), // target correct text panel     
    left, toggleText;
  // store position first time
  if (!isActive && isNaN($box.data('left')) )  {
    $box.data('left', $box.css('left'));
  }
  // set left position and icon text based on active or not
  left = isActive ? $box.data('left') : 0;
  toggleText = isActive ? '+' : '-';
  // toggle panel
  $text.animate({width: 'toggle'});
  // toggle active class and animate
  $box.toggleClass('active').animate({ left: left }, 500);
  $box.children('span').html(toggleText);
});
```

You may also want to look at using `stop()` inline with the animations in case user clicks on box before animations complete

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k0k3xg9r/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer CSS animations. They are generally much smoother, but also more difficult to manage timings. Here is a CSS based approach to your problem:

CSS for transitions:

```
.box      {  transition: left .5s;}
.box.on   {  left: 0 !important; }

.panel    {  transition: width .5s; }
.panel.on {  width: 65% !important; }
```

Javascript to toggle the `on` class:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  var $t = $(this);

  $(".panel.on").not($t.next('.panel')).removeClass('on');
  $(".box.on").not($t).removeClass('on');

  if ($t.hasClass('on')) {
    $t.next('.panel')
      .removeClass('on')
      .one('transitionend', function() {
        $t.removeClass('on');
      });
  } else {
    if ($t.css('left') === "0px") {
      $t.addClass('on').next('.panel').addClass('on');
    } else {
      $t.addClass('on')
        .one('transitionend', function() {
          $t.next('.panel').addClass('on');
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/82vg42b1/